Salesforce retrieve tab, apexclass, apextriggers, lwc-app, custom field
I'm new to cicd of salesforce and I'm trying to sync from dev hub to my project.
This how I created the project/repo, the -x is important to create the manifest/package.xml,
sf project generate -n sfdemo -x
target dir = /home/uniwinux/repo
  create sfdemo/config/project-scratch-def.json
  create sfdemo/README.md
  create sfdemo/sfdx-project.json
  create sfdemo/manifest/package.xml
  create sfdemo/.vscode/extensions.json
  create sfdemo/.husky/pre-commit
  create sfdemo/.vscode/launch.json
  create sfdemo/.vscode/settings.json
  create sfdemo/force-app/main/default/lwc/.eslintrc.json
  create sfdemo/force-app/main/default/aura/.eslintrc.json
  create sfdemo/scripts/soql/account.soql
  create sfdemo/scripts/apex/hello.apex
  create sfdemo/.forceignore
  create sfdemo/.gitignore
  create sfdemo/.prettierignore
  create sfdemo/.prettierrc
  create sfdemo/jest.config.js
  create sfdemo/package.json

The manifest/package.xml value is,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTestSuite</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <version>62.0</version>
</Package>

Go to my browser and login to salesforce dev hub and created some object, tab 'Employee, Skill, Manager', apexclass 'HelloWorld', apextrigger 'TriggerStudent.trigger', tabs, app 'My App LWC', custom field, etc.
I login using 'sf org login jwt' on my cli.
Now I want to retrieve it on my project sfdemo,

sf project retrieve start -o $user --manifest manifest/package.xml
It only retrieve apextrigger 'TriggerStudent.trigger' and some folders but no tab, app, apexclass, custom field, etc.
I learned to retrieve apexclass and custom field by adding these on the manifest/package.xml,

<types>
    <members>HelloWorld</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Account.Hello_World__c</members>
    <name>CustomField</name>
</types>

How do I retrieve the rest like tab and app 'My App LWC'?


Below is the xml for custom application and custom tab:
    <types>
        <members>My_App_LWC</members>
        <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomTab</name>
    </types>

Note: You can find the information for items in xml from the below link.
Reference link : XML Package to retrieve metadata from Org

Thanks!  It works.

I tried to use the package.xml with everything, it download everything.  I think the best way to do this first is to do it on the scratch org and not on the dev hub.  So that you only have a small foot print.

Additionally, if you want to make your life easier if you are using package.xml for retrieving or pushing then you can use this extension for vs code XML Generator

Unfortunately this is for CICD on Gitlab.
